# Limit upload file size and redirect user to error page if limit exceeds

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, lighttpd, httpd.conf, upload

Is it possible to redirect user to file `file too big` page

when POST request size exceeds specified limit?

I am aware about max-request-size option, but it gives just static page that cannot be overloaded.

I am thinking to create a rewrite rule which takes

content-size from request body as input 
and redirects to error page

**UPDATE**

now we use nginx as front-end. Any new suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to do this using something like:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  client_max_body_size 10m; # or whatever size limit you want
  error_page 413 /custompage.html; # you can also use a named location here if you like
}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Comment: but this won't work with most of modern browsers - unfortunaley they can't handle 413 properly. So, I'm afraid there's no solution to this problem (well, unless you can patch all current browsers)

Comment: You can change the status code to anything else with error_page if you don't want to actually return 413 to the client.  error_page 413 =403 /custompage.html; will use 403, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to set `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to corresponding value in `php.ini`.

Comment: We are not at php.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @quanta post, you can also put a lower value in php and use php to display the error and make the redirection correctly. It can be made in other scripting languages also  :-)

Comment: I didn't mention our server side stack. PHP <> whole world :)